# Web application tell request from iframe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

In asp.net, is there any way to tell if a request is from "iframe"??

Thank you very much

Comment: No, `iframe`s usually function exactly like a true window or tab.

Answer (score 3):

Not if you do not have control over the request. If someone creates an a page with an iFrame and then loads your content in it, there will be no difference in the request.

If you are making the request, then you can add a query string parameter such as ?fromIFrame=1 and tell your asp.net application that it is coming from an iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer from javascript

```
var isIframe = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
```

Then you can use some Ajax request, or maybe enable pageMethods and send that information server-side.